# Sherlock and The beast - issue

Tags: java, algorithm

Question:
Sherlock Holmes is getting paranoid about Professor Moriarty, his arch-enemy. All his efforts to subdue Moriarty have been in vain. These days Sherlock is working on a problem with Dr. Watson. Watson mentioned that the CIA has been facing weird problems with their supercomputer, 'The Beast', recently.

This afternoon, Sherlock received a note from Moriarty, saying that he has infected 'The Beast' with a virus. Moreover, the note had the number N printed on it. After doing some calculations, Sherlock figured out that the key to remove the virus is the largest Decent Number having N digits.

A Decent Number has the following properties:

- 3, 5, or both as its digits. No other digit is allowed.
- Number of times 3 appears is divisible by 5.
- Number of times 5 appears is divisible by 3.

Meanwhile, the counter to the destruction of 'The Beast' is running very fast. Can you save 'The Beast', and find the key before Sherlock?

I am trying to solve "Sherlock and the beast" problem (above) in hackerrank and here is what I ended with -

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = s.nextInt();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        int subject = s.nextInt();
        if(isPerfectlyDivisible(subject, 3)) {
            System.out.println(stringBuilder("5", subject));
            continue;
        }

        if (isPerfectlyDivisible(subject, 5)) {
            System.out.println(stringBuilder("3", subject));
            continue;
        }

        if(!isPerfectlyDivisible(subject, 5) && !(isPerfectlyDivisible(subject, 3))) {
            List<Integer> multipliers = dividedMultipliers(subject);
            if (multipliers.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("-1");
            } else {
                System.out.println(stringBuilder("5", multipliers.get(0))+stringBuilder("3", multipliers.get(1)));
            }
        }
    }
}

private static boolean isPerfectlyDivisible(int n, int divider) {
    if (n < divider) return false;
    if (n%divider == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

private static List<Integer> dividedMultipliers(int n) {
    List<Integer> multipliers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=n;i>0;i--) {  
      if( (i%3 == 0) && ((n-i)%5 == 0)) {
          multipliers.add(i);
          multipliers.add(n-i);
          break;
      }    
    }
    return multipliers;
}

private static String stringBuilder(String s, int times) {
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<times;i++) {
        buffer.append(s);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

}
```

There were test cases failing for this. I tried looking at one of the failing test cases whose input is

```
5
2194
12002
21965
55140
57634
```

Surprisingly for `21965` the output is all 5's whereas my code above returns all 3's..which seems to be the expected output..Not sure where the issue? Any insights would be helpful

Comment: A small explanation of what the problem is would be better. Some of us are aware of Sherlock and (Beauty and the) Beast. But not the problem you are talking about :)

Comment: 21965 is divisible by 5, but the largest decent number is not one that consists of 3s only; it is one that has 21960 3s and 5 3s. Get rid of the special cases.

Comment: Sorry about the assumption Vinod, posted the question so `the beauty` is out of the picture now..
@MOehm I just pasted the question from hackerrank, doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: @g0c00l.g33k: Why not? You are looking for the largest decent number, so you should maximise the number of 5s, no?

Comment: @MOehm Ah, I see what you mean...Could you please add it as an answer - I will accept it please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the largest decent number, so you should maximise the number of 5s. For example, 21965 is divisible by 5, but the largest 21965-digit decent number is not one that consists of 3s only; it is one that has 21960 5s and 5 3s.

Your `dividedMultipliers` routine already goes for the most 5s, but treating a number that is divisible by 5 as special undermines that logic; it will create the least optimum decent number.

Get rid of that special case. (You could also get rid of the other special case which checks against a number consisting of only 5s, because `dividedMultipliers` handles that case immediately in the first iteration.)

Comment: @JimMischel: Yes, of course. (I've copied that from my above comment, which has the same mistake.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for your question ;)

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = in.nextInt();
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){
        int n = in.nextInt();
        findSolution(n);
    }
}

public static void findSolution(int n){

    int a = n/3;
    int temp = n;
    int  i;
    boolean flag = false;
    for(i=a;i>=0;i--){

        temp = n-3*i;
        if(temp%5 == 0){

            flag = true;
            break;

        }

    }
    if(flag){
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
            if(j<=i*3)
                System.out.print("5");
            else
                System.out.print("3");    
        }                
        System.out.println();
    }
    else
        System.out.println("-1");
}
}
```

Comment: Adding an explanation of *why* this answers the question will make the answer more useful to the person asking the question, and to future visitors.